# LSTM Initial state from Dense layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am using a `lstm` on time series data. I have features about the time series that are not time dependent. Imagine company stocks for the series and stuff like company location in the non-time series features. This is not the usecase, but it is the same idea. For this example, let's just predict the next value in the time series.

So a simple example would be:

```
feature_input = Input(shape=(None, data.training_features.shape[1]))
dense_1 = Dense(4, activation='relu')(feature_input)
dense_2 = Dense(8, activation='relu')(dense_1)

series_input = Input(shape=(None, data.training_series.shape[1]))
lstm = LSTM(8)(series_input, initial_state=dense_2)
out = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(lstm)

model = Model(inputs=[feature_input,series_input], outputs=out)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=["mape"])
```

however, I am just not sure on how to specify the initial state on the list correctly. I get

```
ValueError: An initial_state was passed that is not compatible with `cell.state_size`. Received `state_spec`=[<keras.engine.topology.InputSpec object at 0x11691d518>]; However `cell.state_size` is (8, 8)
```

which I can see is caused by the 3d batch dimension. I tried using Flatten, Permutation, and Resize layers but I don't believe that is correct. What am I missing and how can I connect these layers?

Comment: Do you have any reference for this approach? I am trying to implement something similar (initializing an RNN with other data) and was surprised that I did not find a good reference for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first problem is that an `LSTM(8)` layer expects two initial states `h_0` and `c_0`, each of dimension `(None, 8)`. That's what it means by "`cell.state_size` is (8, 8)" in the error message.

If you only have one initial state `dense_2`, maybe you can switch to `GRU` (which requires only `h_0`). Or, you can transform your `feature_input` into two initial states.

The  second problem is that `h_0` and `c_0` are of shape `(batch_size, 8)`, but your `dense_2` is of shape `(batch_size, timesteps, 8)`. You need to deal with the time dimension before using `dense_2` as initial states.

So maybe you can change your input shape into `(data.training_features.shape[1],)` or take average over timesteps with `GlobalAveragePooling1D`.

A working example would be:

```
feature_input = Input(shape=(5,))
dense_1_h = Dense(4, activation='relu')(feature_input)
dense_2_h = Dense(8, activation='relu')(dense_1_h)
dense_1_c = Dense(4, activation='relu')(feature_input)
dense_2_c = Dense(8, activation='relu')(dense_1_c)

series_input = Input(shape=(None, 5))
lstm = LSTM(8)(series_input, initial_state=[dense_2_h, dense_2_c])
out = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(lstm)
model = Model(inputs=[feature_input,series_input], outputs=out)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=["mape"])
```

Comment: This line "The first problem is that an LSTM(8) layer expects two initial states h_0 and c_0, each of dimension (None, 8). That's what it means by "cell.state_size is (8, 8)" in the error message." is so important to understand `initial_state` but it's nowhere on tf's documentation! Thanks!