# Setting initial state of LSTM layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following code:

```
units = 1024
lstm_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units)

dim = tf.zeros([64,1024])

output, hidden = lstm_layer(embedded_data, initial_state = dim)
```

I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: An `initial_state` was passed that is 
not compatible with `cell.state_size`.
 Received `state_spec`=
ListWrapper([InputSpec(shape=(64, 1024), ndim=2)]);
 however `cell.state_size` is [1024, 1024]
```

When I do it with a GRU cell instead of a LSTM cell, it works fine. But for a LSTM cell, this code does not work. I realize that LSTM takes two parameters, hence the code asking for a cell state of [1024,1024], but I don't know how to set the initial state. I tried

```
initial_state = [dim, dim]
```

and that doesn't work either, as it gives me

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).
```

I referenced [LSTM Initial state from Dense layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233400/lstm-initial-state-from-dense-layer) but doesn't seem to resolve my issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference if anybody needs solving on this problem:

The problem is the output. Just using `tf.zeros([64,1024])` works fine, you just need to have three outputs:

```
output, hidden_h,hidden_c = lstm_layer(embedded_data, initial_state = [dim,dim])
```